# How to calculate Date difference between two records in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello all my `df` has 3  columns and 100+ rows and looks like

```
PID  Record_date     DOB
123  25-02-2009  22-08-1944
165  20-04-2017  22-08-1944
```

I tried to calculate age for the PID but resulted like this

```
PID  Record_date     DOB        Age
123  25-02-2009   22-08-1944    65
165  20-04-2017   22-08-1944    73
```

I have calculated age for the PID by the below code

```
df$Age <- as.numeric(df$Record_date - df$DOB)/365
df$Age <- round (df$Age, digits = 0)
```

My expected Result and outcome

```
PID  Record_date        DOB     Age
123  25-02-2009    22-08-1944   64
165  20-04-2017    22-08-1944   72
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

additional solution

```
   library(tidyverse)
   library(lubridate)
    df %>% 
      mutate(across(c(Record_date, DOB), dmy),
             age = (Record_date - DOB) %/% dyears(1))
    
      PID Record_date        DOB age
    1 123  2009-02-25 1944-08-22  64
    2 165  2017-04-20 1944-08-22  72
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `period` object from the `lubridate` package and extract information of years.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(Record_date, DOB), dmy),
         Age = as.period(DOB %--% Record_date)$year)

#   PID Record_date        DOB Age
# 1 123  2009-02-25 1944-08-22  64
# 2 165  2017-04-20 1944-08-22  72
```

If you remove `$year`, you can get detailed information of period:

```
#                 Age
# 64y 6m  3d 0H 0M 0S
# 72y 7m 29d 0H 0M 0S
```

***Note:*** *`DOB %--% Record_date` is the shortcut of `interval(DOB, Record_date)`.*

Answer (score 0):

If you `round` the values, the numbers which you have got is correct. Perhaps, you want to `floor` them?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(-1, as.Date, '%d-%m-%Y'), 
         age = as.integer(floor((Record_date - DOB)/365)))

#  PID Record_date        DOB age
#1 123  2009-02-25 1944-08-22  64
#2 165  2017-04-20 1944-08-22  72
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(PID = c(123L, 165L), Record_date = c("25-02-2009", 
"20-04-2017"), DOB = c("22-08-1944", "22-08-1944")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: It works but i face minor errors  in date difference between one day like Record Date :31-12-1993  and DOB : 1927-01-01  i get age 67 for the PID but expected age  result is 66  can yo help me out

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
age <- function(dob, age.day = today(), units = "years", floor = TRUE) {
  calc.age = interval(dob, age.day) / duration(num = 1, units = units)
  if (floor) return(as.integer(floor(calc.age)))
  return(calc.age)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

```
diffyear <- function(x, y){
  d <- difftime(x, y)
  z <- as.integer(d)
  years <- as.Date(z, origin = "0000-01-01")
  format(years, "%Y")
}

df1$Record_date <- as.Date(df1$Record_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
df1$DOB <- as.Date(df1$DOB, "%d-%m-%Y")
diffyear(df1[[2]], df1[[3]])
#[1] "64" "72"
```

Now assign the return value to the new column.